# Why numpy vectorised function does not apply to each element

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to apply a vectorised function to a 1D NumPy array (test).

If an element is greater than a certain threshold the function is applied, otherwise a 0 is returned.

Passing the function on the whole array gives an array of zeros (result #1)

Yet this works for some slices of the large array(result #2) and a small array (result #3)

Can you help me understand why this is?

```
import numpy as np
test = np.array([-58.08281  , -47.07844  , -39.38589  , -38.244213 , -36.04118  ,
       -35.17719  , -47.651756 , -47.123497 , -38.47037  , -31.427711 ,
       -35.980206 , -39.04678  , -43.247276 , -29.217781 , -26.16616  ,
       -23.175611 , -19.073223 , -19.573145 , -19.291908 , -19.084608 ,
       -24.24286  , -26.768343 , -29.40547  , -42.254036 , -32.5126   ,
       -27.8232   , -26.521381 , -18.53816  , -16.300032 , -14.897881 ,
       -11.96727  , -11.895884 , -11.958228 , -11.689035 , -19.331993 ,
       -22.528988 , -14.850136 , -10.7898   , -10.738896 , -11.510415 ,
       -11.297523 , -14.9558525, -18.261246 , -20.11386  , -35.434853 ,
       -36.547577 , -29.713285 , -35.055378 , -19.717499 , -15.524372 ,
       -14.905738 , -11.690297 , -12.295127 , -14.571337 , -14.457521 ,
       -20.896961 , -35.145    , -39.106945 , -20.592056 , -19.292147 ,
       -21.957949 , -20.131369 , -31.953508 , -24.577961 , -23.88112  ,
       -16.549093 , -16.742077 , -22.181223 , -21.692726 , -34.572075 ,
       -20.111103 , -18.57012  , -12.833547 , -11.325545 , -12.807129 ,
       -11.844269 , -19.830124 , -21.79983  , -18.484238 , -12.855567 ,
       -11.830711 , -14.83697  , -14.618052 , -19.990686 , -30.934792 ,
       -27.72318  , -17.222315 , -14.099125 , -16.516563 , -15.129327 ,
       -19.21385  , -41.145554 , -37.12835  , -20.674335 , -17.670841 ,
       -26.641182 , -26.721628 , -29.708376 , -16.29707  , -15.220005 ,
       -11.475418 ,  35.859955 , -10.404102 ,  35.160667 , -11.339685 ,
       -17.627815 , -18.65314  , -25.346134 , -38.297813 , -22.460407 ,
       -21.334377 , -16.922516 , -10.733174 ,  35.263527 ,  35.078003 ,
        35.26928  ,  35.44266  ,  35.89205  , -10.965962 , -16.772722 ,
       -10.638295 ,  35.37294  ,  35.32364  ,  35.271263 ,  35.900078 ,
        35.145794 , -12.282233 , -14.206524 , -18.138363 , -37.339016 ,
       -26.27323  , -27.531588 , -25.00942  , -13.963585 , -12.315678 ,
       -10.978365 ,  35.439877 , -10.534686 , -11.77856  , -12.630129 ,
       -22.29188  , -32.74709  , -29.052572 , -16.526686 , -18.223225 ,
       -19.174236 , -18.920668 , -34.266537 , -23.23388  , -19.992903 ,
       -13.9729805, -16.85691  , -20.88271  , -21.805904 , -24.517344 ,
       -17.412155 , -15.050234 ,  35.047886 , -10.27907  , -10.765995 ,
       -11.394721 , -34.574    , -18.185272 , -15.156159 , -10.370025 ,
       -11.406872 , -13.781429 , -13.863158 , -24.35263  , -29.509377 ,
       -24.758411 , -14.150916 , -13.686075 , -15.366934 , -14.149103 ,
       -22.916718 , -35.810047 , -33.369896 , -17.931974 , -18.65556  ,
       -28.330248 , -27.015589 , -23.890095 , -15.020579 , -13.920487 ,
        35.49385  ,  35.613037 ,  35.326546 ,  35.1469   , -12.024554 ,
       -17.770742 , -18.414755 , -31.574192 , -35.00205  , -20.591629 ,
       -21.097118 , -14.166552 ,  35.61772  ,  35.196175 ,  35.884003 ,
        35.032402 ,  35.289963 ,  35.18595  , -36.364285 , -10.158181 ,
        35.040634 ,  35.349873 ,  35.31796  ,  35.87602  ,  35.88828  ,
        35.086105 , -12.404961 , -13.550255 , -20.19417  , -35.630135 ,
       -23.762396 , -27.673418 , -19.928736 , -12.206515 , -11.781338 ,
        35.307823 ,  35.67385  , -10.780588 , -11.199528 , -13.561855 ,
       -24.982666 , -30.838753 , -25.138466 , -16.61114  , -20.002995 ,
       -18.823566 , -21.581133 , -25.644733 , -22.914455 , -17.489904 ,
       -13.714966 , -18.483316 , -20.454823 , -25.238888 , -20.592503 ,
       -17.511456 , -13.5111885,  35.399975 , -10.711888 , -10.577221 ,
       -13.2071705, -27.878649 , -16.227467 , -13.394671 ,  35.33075  ,
       -10.933496 , -12.903596 , -13.261947 , -23.191689 , -36.082005 ,
       -26.252464 , -14.935854 , -14.955426 , -16.291502 , -15.563564 ,
       -27.91648  , -30.43707  , -27.09887  , -16.93166  , -19.03229  ,
       -26.68034  , -26.50705  , -22.435007 , -15.312309 , -13.67744  ,
        35.70387  ,  35.197517 ,  35.21866  ,  35.759956 , -12.934032 ,
       -18.348143 , -19.073929 , -36.864773 , -32.881073 , -20.560263 ,
       -20.530846 , -13.128365 ,  35.65545  ,  35.465275 ,  35.028538 ,
        35.842434 ,  35.676643 , -17.01441  , -17.217728 ,  35.667717 ,
        35.871662 ,  35.92965  ,  35.316013 ,  35.096027 ,  35.02661  ,
        35.988937 , -12.0597515, -13.201061 , -20.259245 , -28.855875 ,
       -21.791933 , -25.400242 , -17.618946 , -11.611944 , -11.329423 ,
        35.063614 ,  35.825493 , -10.553531 , -10.820301 , -13.883024 ,
       -22.231556 , -26.921532 , -31.872276 , -18.039211 , -19.713062 ,
       -20.517511 , -21.620483 , -26.919012 , -20.787134 , -17.330051 ,
       -13.198881 , -15.984946 , -19.181019 , -21.50328  , -25.311642 ,
       -18.11811  , -14.696231 , -10.136784 , -10.480961 , -11.110486 ,
       -13.739718 , -28.865023 , -15.966995 , -13.198223 ,  35.18759  ,
       -10.803377 , -12.718526 , -13.597855 , -23.472122 , -34.405643 ,
       -24.122065 , -14.643904 , -14.425363 , -15.651573 , -15.197855 ,
       -25.13602  , -33.207695 , -26.908777 , -17.217882 , -19.061764 ,
       -27.06517  , -28.88142  , -21.721449 , -14.84623  , -12.997027 ,
        35.853565 ,  35.51484  ,  35.660423 ,  35.982292 , -12.461762 ,
       -17.52755  , -19.008127 , -32.69878  , -30.82928  , -20.193447 ,
       -19.172876 , -12.901536 ,  35.05082  ,  35.915546 ,  35.254303 ,
        35.797028 , -14.470562 , -22.461277 , -15.07134  ,  35.970448 ,
        35.198704 ,  35.945583 ,  35.362762 ,  35.306732 ,  35.064957 ,
        35.10975  , -11.703257 , -13.411005 , -20.08778  , -28.905445 ,
       -22.59493  , -25.155657 , -17.814808 , -11.842859 , -11.154184 ,
        35.989094 ,  35.854362 , -10.2389765, -10.827884 , -14.010275 ,
       -25.168896 , -33.99552  , -22.858255 , -16.562387 , -19.22073  ,
       -18.317003 , -23.036928 , -25.22068  , -21.934307 , -16.469448 ,
       -13.88927  , -18.307293 , -20.485218 , -29.06332  , -19.628113 ,
       -16.496414 , -12.351503 ,  35.66623  , -10.330103 , -10.866837 ,
       -16.813847 , -21.454565 , -15.892494 , -12.269305 ,  35.174488 ,
       -11.898882 , -13.1494465, -15.517578 , -35.11971  , -29.069548 ,
       -19.153015 , -13.194953 , -14.334308 , -14.483275 , -15.592762 ,
       -30.123589 , -38.262245 , -24.752253 , -17.36696  , -22.627728 ,
       -29.787828 , -44.489254 , -17.438164 , -13.678364 , -11.26264  ,
        35.92086  ,  35.600876 ,  35.231567 ,  35.960655 , -13.438512 ,
       -16.794493 , -19.414097 , -33.008324 , -23.844492 , -18.63253  ,
       -17.060545 , -10.566847 ,  35.735447 ,  35.061024 ,  35.95225  ,
       -11.117262 , -18.978222 , -39.73106  , -11.048341 ,  35.58616  ,
        35.699783 ,  35.32885  ,  35.09172  ,  35.119743 ,  35.753242 ,
        35.73512  , -12.641587 , -14.861554 , -25.59355  , -29.808552 ,
       -24.463276 , -26.617489 , -15.665792 , -11.706967 , -11.054789 ,
        35.413254 ,  35.13033  , -10.968152 , -11.514641 , -17.074472 ,
       -31.623056 , -40.51703  , -18.116985 , -15.995826 , -18.33452  ,
       -17.266975 , -28.274193 , -24.104795 , -21.711021 , -15.209898 ,
       -15.003292 , -20.39471  , -21.562126 , -34.197975 , -16.957975 ,
       -14.923981 , -10.418877 ,  35.874657 , -10.214642 , -11.880876 ])

test2 = np.array([5,5,5])

Thresh = -10
Ratio = 5

#Defining function
def gr(x):
    if x >=Thresh:
        return Thresh + (x-Thresh)/Ratio
    else:
        return 0
#vectorising function
gr_v = np.vectorize(gr)

#RESULTS
##1
print(sum(gr_v(test))) #0
##2
print(sum(gr_v(test2)))
##3
print(sum(gr_v(test[200:250])))
```

Comment: This is interesting. It is the type inference. Quite a gotcha. See my answer below.

Comment: I know the `vectorize` docs are long and boring, but pays to read it.  This error has come up several times recently,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as a remark, know that [np.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) "function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Therefore it is the same as:

```
l = [gr(x) for x in test]
sum(l)
-80.41708859999999
```

To use a vectorize implementation you can do:

```
np.sum(Thresh + (test[test>=Thresh]-Thresh)/Ratio)
-80.41708859999999
```

As time performance is concerned:

```
%timeit np.sum(Thresh + (test[test>=Thresh]-Thresh)/Ratio)
13.8 µs ± 864 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit sum(gr_v(test))
217 µs ± 5.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The actual vectorized implemantation is 15x faster with this `test` size.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the inherent property of vectorisation. If the first output of your vectorised function is integer 0, then the entire output is off. While this behaviour of `vectorise` is a bit memorising, I can provide a rather simple fix.
Instead of using

```
def gr(x):
    if x >=Thresh:
        return Thresh + (x-Thresh)/Ratio
    else:
         return 0
```

which returns:

```
0
-21.0
-12.044083
```

rewrite the function as :

```
def gr(x):
    if x >=Thresh:
         return Thresh + (x-Thresh)/Ratio
    else:
        return 0.0
```

it returns:

```
-80.41708859999999
-21.0
-12.044083
```

The purpose of returning `0.0` instead of `0` is to have a float(0) instead of int(0) as your output. It also explains why your codes work for your `test2` and `test[200:250]` arrays, because both have positive numbers as their first element, therefore what is returned by `gr_v` is a float, but not `int(0)`.
Hope that it helps!

Comment: You can just do `0.0` or specify the output type when defining the vectorized function: `gr_v = np.vectorize(gr, otypes=[float])`

Answer (score 0):

It is something to do with type inference:

Try this:

```
gr_v = np.vectorize(gr, otypes=[np.float])
```

And this fixes it (note the .0):

```
Thresh = -10.0
Ratio = 5.0

#Defining function
def gr(x):
    if x >=Thresh:
        return Thresh + (x-Thresh)/Ratio
    else:
        return 0.0
#vectorising function
gr_v = np.vectorize(gr)
```